# Como especificar um caso de uso abstrato?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, uml

[image: Exemplo de caso de uso]

Estou fazendo a especificação destes casos de uso e tenho estes casos de usos abstratos, a pergunta é a seguinte, eu preciso detalhar os casos de usos abstratos, ou apenas os especializados(ou generalizados), ou seja, no caso de listar usuários, eu deveria especificar os casos de uso listar atendentes e listar supervisores, ou apenas especificar o caso de uso listar usuários e colocar as condições de listar atendentes ou supervisores como fluxos alternativos?

Caso nenhuma destas afirmações esteja correta, qual seria a forma fácil de representar essas ações no diagrama, de maneira certa e que fique fácil de especificar posteriormente?